# What are all the sizes of resolutions in Android screens?

Tags: android, screen-resolution

My question is the following: **at this moment, how many types of Android resolutions do exists? And what are its sizes given in pixels?**

Example: one of then is the 240x320 (used in Galaxy 5).

**Context**: right now, I'm working with an app that calls different methods given different resolutions. It's not related with resolution-independent development, but with user-experience, given hes mobile type. I've searched a little bit but I could not found a "table" or a "list" with these informations.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this article
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Resume: think about resolutions if they were random. It's unpredictable value. So, it's better to develop for different configurations (which are fixed), like small-medium-large screens or low-medium-hight dpi.

However, in the link below there a table that contains most of used resolutions
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing

Comment: Hi biovamp. The first link you passed I've already readed before, but the second I haven't seen and fits in good ways my objective. Thanks for the fast answer.

Comment: @mthama you are welcome. But, actually, second link is just a part of first article, so read it more closely :)